# Primes of the form $3^n +2$

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers

There seem to be many results on primes of the form $2^n +1$ but I can not find anything on powers of other numbers plus a constant. I was thinking that for powers of odd numbers  adding $1$ was not sensible as it would be even.  I therefore thought of adding $2$ and for $3^n +2$ it seems to give primes for the first values of $n$.  Is there some general theory of this sort of number or any work on similar numbers maybe $p^n + 2 , p$ an odd prime?

Comment: $3^{5} + 2 = 245$

Comment: Look at wikipedia : Gaussian Mersenne primes, Eisenstein Mersenne primes,Repunit primes

Comment: See [A057735](https://oeis.org/A057735).

Comment: Adding to my first comment: $3 | 5^{2} + 2 = 27$, $3 | 7^{2} + 2 = 51$ and $11 | 9^{6}+2 = 531443$.

Comment: See too [A051783](https://oeis.org/A051783) for a table of the $n$ solutions and the theorem concerning perfect numbers.